# geting Someclass@c3648626 value from p:selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

have a little problem with taking data from selectonemenu. 
In my view i have three selectonemenu, one for each data table( Korisnik, Odsek, Predmet ) and on submit button it should insert selected values to the fourth table (Drzi). Values are populated from list for each selectonemenu.

View:

```
<h:body>
    <center>
        <h:form>
            poz!
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" border="2" bgcolor="lightgray">
                <h:outputText value="Predmet"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 100%" value="#{dodela.akrPred}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Izaberite predmet" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{pred.akrList}" var="predmet" itemValue="#{dodela.akrPred}" itemLabel="#{predmet.akronim}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Profesor"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{dodela.imeProf}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Izaberite profesora" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{kor.korList}" var="koris" itemValue="#{dodela.imeProf}" itemLabel="#{koris.imeprez}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Odsek"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 100%" value="#{dodela.akrOdsek}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Izaberite odsek" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{odsk.odList}" var="ods" itemValue="#{dodela.akrOdsek}" itemLabel="#{ods.akronim}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Potvrdi" action="#{dodela.dodela()}" update="msgs"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </center>          
</h:body>
```

and function in Model:

```
    public String dodela(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    System.out.println("Profesor je " + imeProf);
    System.out.println("Predmet je" + akrPred);
    System.out.println("Odsek je" + akrOdsek);
    Drzi d = Drzi.getDrzi( imeProf, akrPred, akrOdsek);
    if(d != null){
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "", "Profesor vec drzi taj predmet na tom odseku.");
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
        return null;
    }
    Drzi.dodaj(imeProf, akrPred, akrOdsek);
    msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", "Uspesno ste dodelili predmet profesoru.");
    context.addMessage(null, msg);
    return "";
}
```

the problem is that im getting:
dataBeans.Korisnik@9000651, 
dataBeans.Predmet@c3648626, 
dataBeans.Odsek@18308e for selected values. The bean is RequestScoped. Using MVC approach, Primefaces 5.0, JSF 2.2.

UPDATE

I was missing Override toString() for my Controlor class's, now it's working

Comment: Do your classes have `toString()` overriden?

Comment: I encourage you to use the `noSelectionOption` attribute from the `f:selectItem` tag instead of giving it a blank value.

Comment: @XtremeBiker ok will do in future, and change

Comment: THX @ACV that was the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `@FacesConverter` because when you have selectMenu and bound your own class to it to choose from, the returned value is just `String` created from `toString()` of chosen element.

You can look at the example in the last tab `ThemeConverter.java`

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Comment: I already try that and getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to dataBeans.Korisnik, but thx to @ACV i manage to solve problem. I was missing toString()

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org/) Converter, and check my solution : [solution SelectOneMenu](http://dajohlopez.blogspot.pe/2015/08/cargando-un-selectonemenu-con.html)